# Convert a list of lists to dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Now I have a list of lists like this:

```
List(
  List(2,(String,String,String......),1,(String,String,String......),1,(String,String,String......)),
  List(3,(String,String,String......),1,(String,String,String......),1,(String,String,String......)),
  List(3,(String,String,String......),2,(String,String,String......),1,(String,String,String......)),
  List(3,(String,String,String......),2,(String,String,String......),2,(String,String,String......)),
  List(3,(String,String,String......),1,(String,String,String......),2,(String,String,String......))
)
```

The output format I expect is following:

```
+-----+------------------+-----+------------------+-----+------------------+
|   _1|                _2|   _3|                _4|   _5|                _6|
+-----+------------------+-----+------------------+-----+------------------+
|2    |(String,String...)|1    |(String,String...)|1    |(String,String...)|
|3    |(String,String...)|1    |(String,String...)|1    |(String,String...)|
|3    |(String,String...)|2    |(String,String...)|1    |(String,String...)|
|3    |(String,String...)|2    |(String,String...)|2    |(String,String...)|
|3    |(String,String...)|1    |(String,String...)|2    |(String,String...)|
+-----+------------------+-----+------------------+-----+------------------+
```

How to do the convert in spark scala? I sincerely hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For testing purpose I created identical test data as mentioned in the question as

```
val nestedList = List(
  List(2,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),1,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),1,("String","String","String","String","String","String")),
  List(3,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),1,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),1,("String","String","String","String","String","String")),
  List(3,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),2,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),1,("String","String","String","String","String","String")),
  List(3,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),2,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),2,("String","String","String","String","String","String")),
  List(3,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),1,("String","String","String","String","String","String"),2,("String","String","String","String","String","String"))
)
```

Now you can *convert the inner list to tuples* (you can change the number of elements in the tuple creation and type cast according to your needs) and call `toDF` and you should get your desired output as

```
nestedList.map(x => (x(0).asInstanceOf[Int], x(1).toString, x(2).asInstanceOf[Int], x(3).toString, x(4).asInstanceOf[Int], x(5).toString)).toDF().show()
```

which should give you

```
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2| _3|                  _4| _5|                  _6|
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
|  2|(String,String,St...|  1|(String,String,St...|  1|(String,String,St...|
|  3|(String,String,St...|  1|(String,String,St...|  1|(String,String,St...|
|  3|(String,String,St...|  2|(String,String,St...|  1|(String,String,St...|
|  3|(String,String,St...|  2|(String,String,St...|  2|(String,String,St...|
|  3|(String,String,St...|  1|(String,String,St...|  2|(String,String,St...|
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thankyou, I have use your method to run my program, it is works very effective. Thanks again!